# Table level triggers in oracle

Tags: triggers, oracle12c

What is table level trigger in Oracle database, is table level trigger and statement level trigger same. If not, what is the difference between them?

Comment: You won't find a reference to "table level triggers" in Oracle documentation.  I find a couple of references from Googling of people using the term to mean a statement-level trigger.  Most of them appear to be non-native English speakers so my wild guess is that there is a translation issue somewhere.

Comment: Exactly, I couldn't find any reference in oracle documentation. But I had attended an online MCQ interview (Oracle pl/sql) for a reputed company. I had a question about this table level trigger. I'm trying to find what it is, since then...no luck.

Comment: I'd guess they meant a statement-level trigger.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the info!